# Error: immediate cannot be moved by a single

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, glibc

I am trying to compile glibc-2.30 for aarch64. I am using very basic configuration:

```
../configure \
  --with-headers=/tmp/headers/include \
  --disable-sanity-checks \
  --enable-kernel=3.18.0
```

No error on configure, but get the following error when running "make":

```
../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: Assembler messages:
../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:78: Error: immediate cannot be moved by a single instruction
```

I assume I have to add a aarch64 specific configure param?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AArch64 assembler emits this error message when it encounters a constant that cannot be encoded in a register. The only constants in the system call wrappers are the system call numbers, so this suggests that your kernel headers are for the wrong architecture, and the system call numbers are incompatible with AArch64. (Kernel headers are architecture-specific and must be installed using a cross-compiler when cross-compiling.)

Comment: Ah! You are correct. I was using 32bit header files. I was under the impression that header files where arch agnostic (as they are source code), but I guess I was wrong :) thanks!