# Error: immediate cannot be moved by a single instruction

Tags: assembly, arm, arm64

I'm trying to move a value into a register but when assembling the program with `as -o test.o test.s` I get the message:

```
test.s: Assembler messages:
test.s:6: Error: immediate cannot be moved by a single instruction
```

the program:

```
.equ SIZE, 2000000000

.global _start

_start:
    mov x1, SIZE
```

`uname -a` produces:

```
Linux ip-172-31-10-254 5.19.0-1025-aws #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 24 01:58:03 UTC 2023 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

From the error message and [Error: immediate cannot be moved by a single](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58577074/error-immediate-cannot-be-moved-by-a-single) I would infer the error message relates to the value being too large to store in the register, but `2000000000` is much smaller than `2^64`. I'm thinking something is misconfigured.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `mov` does not take a full 64 bit immediate (it can't, since the instruction itself is only 32 bits). You might want to use `ldr x1, =SIZE` and let the tools figure out the best way which is likely going to be a load from a nearby literal pool.

Comment: That is interesting thankyou, is there documentation on usage of `mov` vs `ldr` you could link?.

Comment: No, it is not the register that won't hold that value, but rather the machine code `mov` instruction.  That `ldr` causes one 32-bit machine code instruction and the one 64-bit piece of data that is referenced by the machine code instruction.  Large constants have to be constructed in some manner, sometimes we can use 2 machine code instructions, other times instruction(s) + separate data.  See [here](http://www.davespace.co.uk/arm/introduction-to-arm/immediates.html) for the limitations of immediates on ARM machine code instructions.

Comment: SIZE is `0x77359400`, with lots of significant bits.  If you pick a rounder number with a simpler bit-pattern, like perhaps `0x77000000`, there are opcodes that can get that into a register in one instruction, so `mov` would be encodeable.  https://godbolt.org/z/7KzY8eeWo (AArch64 can `mov` values with their set bits close together, with an immediate + a rotate count.  Or repeated bit-patterns with contiguous set bits, like `0x5555...` or `0xff00ff00...`)

Comment: Actually only the 32 bit assembler is clever enough to generate efficient code for `ldr` so you can always use that there. Apparently the 64 bit one forces a literal pool access for `ldr` even if it could be encoded more efficiently. I wonder why.

Comment: @old_timer Which common arm assembler does not support `=...` operands?

Comment: Other than the lack of optimization this is just a duplicate of other answers.   assembly language is specific to the assembler in at least one prior answer a user came back with it didnt optimize and/or some form of lack of support for the same syntax (perhaps from arm or keil (arm)  tools).   You cant assume anything about a targets assembly language within some nth tool out there, but likewise I would expect =symbol to be there in general but =123456 some number, not necessarily and then the optimization based on prior answers to this is not always there so not always the best solution.

Comment: this can also be solved with mov x1,SIZE&0xFFFF0000 movk x1,SIZE&0x0000FFFF less bytes and possibly faster since there is no stall for a load.  on other gas assembly languages this type of syntax sometimes wants to go through gcc (yet another assembly language), but appeared to work with gas for aarch64